# Problema al realizar consulta con CodeIgniter no consigo comparar 2 campos

Tags: codeigniter, sql

estoy creando un reporte de productos en el que busco listar todos los productos con las cantidades vendidas, el precio, el costo, etc Gracias a la ayuda de algunos amigos del grupo estoy dando algunos pasos pero estoy atascado. Les explico un poco mi problema..

En mi **MODELO**. En el **where** hago la comparación de entre el campo `id_producto` de la tabla producto y el campo `producto_id_detalle_ventas` de la tabla detalle de ventas

```
**public function getVentasProductos()
{

    $this->db->select("dv.*,sum(dv.cantidad_detalle_ventas) as cantidad,p.id_producto,p.nombre_producto,p.proveedor_id_producto,p.stock_producto,pro.nombre_proveedores as proveedor,p.pCosto_producto, sum(importe_detalle_ventas) as importe,p.precio_producto,p.codigo_producto");
    $this->db->from("detalle_ventas dv");
    $this->db->join("productos p","p.id_producto = dv.producto_id_detalle_ventas");
    $this->db->join("proveedores pro","pro.id_proveedores = p.proveedor_id_producto");
    $this->db->where("dv.producto_id_detalle_ventas","pro.id_proveedores");
    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    if ($resultados->num_rows()>0) 
    {
        return $resultados->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}**
```

cuando hago la comparación de este modo no me estira nada, me devuelve todo `NULL`, pero cuando comparo con código de producto cargado a mano `$this->db->where("dv.producto_id_detalle_ventas",12);`me estira los datos correctamente. Alguien puede mostrarme cual es mi error x favor? Adjunto tb mi Controlador:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("Ventas_models");
}
public function index()
{   $fechaInicio = $this->input->post("fechainicio");
    $fechaFin = $this->input->post("fechafin");
    if ($this->input->post("buscar")) //pregunta si se presiono el boton buscar
    {
        $productos = $this->Ventas_models->getVentasProductosByDate($fechaInicio, $fechaFin);
    }
    else
    {
        $productos = $this->Ventas_models->getVentasProductos();
    }
    $data = array
    (
        'productos' => $productos, // se carga en el array la variable ventas q se obtuvo en el if de arriba 
        //'total' => $total
    );
    var_dump($data);
    $this->load->view("layouts/header");
    $this->load->view("layouts/aside");
    $this->load->view("admin/reportes/Rep_Productos", $data);
    $this->load->view("layouts/footer");
}
```

y otra esta consulta me devuelve solo un registro no me estira la lista completa de los productos. Se q no es algo medio básico, pero estoy empezando y me cuesta todavía un poco.

desde ya muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando haces:

```
$this->db->where("dv.producto_id_detalle_ventas", "pro.id_proveedores");
```

Le estás pasando un string, resultando en algo como:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE dv.producto_id_detalle_ventas = 'pro.id_proveedores'
```

Y claro, no hay ningún elemento en `dv` con esa `producto_id_detalle_ventas`.
Tendrías que escribir la condición del WHERE directamente:

```
$this->db->where("dv.producto_id_detalle_ventas = pro.id_proveedores");
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias x la respuesta amigo, el problema q si hago de esa forma en las columnas q hago las sumas me suma toda la columna. y yo necesito que sume solo los q tienen ese numero de id. ademas esta consulta retorna solo un resultado no me estira los demas productos. hay algun otro error q puedas ver en mi codigo?

Comment: Para conseguir eso tienes que utilizar GROUP BY junto con el SUM: https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Fundamentos-de-SQL-Agrupaciones-y-funciones-de-agregacion.aspx

Comment: Que genial!!! muchísimas gracias amigo!! me funciono perfecto!!